# uninitialized constant Ruby on rails new controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This line in my stands_controller.rb file:

```
@stand_items = Stand_Item.where("stand_id = " + (params[:id]).to_s)
```

causes the error:

```
uninitialized constant StandsController::Stand_Item
```

But, I have a file named: stand_items_controller.rb with the contents:

```
class StandItemsController < ApplicationController  
end
```

I have tried many constant names such as StandItem, Standitem, Stand_item and plurals of all those but no success.

What is the correct constant name? Is there some place where rails stores it?

I have this same concept working elsewhere in the code:
I have the line:

```
  @mark_count = Markstand.where("stand_id = " + (params[:id]).to_s)
```

directly above the line causing the error, and it gives no error. Markstand is the constant name for the file markstands_controller.rb which has the contents:

```
class MarkstandsController < ApplicationController
end
```

**EDIT 1** 
This is how I made the controller:

```
bin/rails generate controller stand_items
```

Comment: do you have a StandItem class in the models directory? (thus will not be generated by a controller generator

Comment: No i do not @TarynEast

Comment: make sure that you have Stand_Item model in the models folder, like what Taryn said.

Comment: I made a model file and it is working now, thanks @TarynEast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've generated a controller but you're trying to use a model from within that controller. You need to generate a model for StandItem and then use that from the controller.

`bin/rails generate model stand_item ...`

See the documentation for the parameters you can pass to setup your model.